# How to change user and execute commands remotely via SSH?

Tags: bash, ssh, tomcat

I want to log through SSH as `user@remote` and then change the user to tomcat, move files to `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps` and re-start the tomcat server in the same script.

Answer (score 3):

```
ssh user@remote sudo -i -u tomcat ...
```

Comment: for > 1 command, replace `...` with `sh -c 'multiple; commands; here'`

Comment: When I use ssh user@remote sudo -i -u tomcat, I get sudo: Illegal option -i